# R segments can't handle transparency?

Tags: r, plot, transparency

In R (3.0.2 in Windows 7) segments() function can't handle transparency?

```
dev.new(width=10,height=10)
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
x = 1:10
y = 10:1
plot(x,y)
segments(0,0,10,10,col=rgb(0,0,0,0.5))
```

This should draw a gray line over the plot, but nothing is drawn. Why?

Comment: I can't reproduce this; the line is drawn for me.  Is the problem in an R figure window, or when writing to file?  Some file types don't support transparency on all systems.

Comment: On my device (Windows 7 R2.15) I can reproduce this in the R figure window *only* if you include the reduced margins on your `par` command. If I comment out that line the behavior of segments is as expected. Is it maybe a problem with the segment being on the edge of the plotting window?

Comment: I get the same behaviour (Win7, R302) with both `segments` and `lines`, but only if at least one of the margins (`mar`) is set to zero.  It is the same when plotting, e.g. `lines(c(2,7),c(2,7),col=rgb(0,1,0,.5))` so it's not dependent on the segment endpoints.  So there's some weird thing going on between the zero-margin parameter and the transparency parameter. Also confirmed a non-transparent color plots fine.   I'm leaning towards a bug in the bowels of the base code.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft -- For the record, plotting to, e.g., a pdf device works fine, so this must have to do with the code implementing the R for Windows plotting device.

Comment: When saving to a PNG it works fine. Not inside R graphics window.

Comment: I've submitted the bug. Let's see what happens. Thank you all!

Comment: Here is the answer to the bug submitted: "This is a function of how Windows' GDI handles translucency (transparency works just fine, but that colour is not transparent). You should be thanking us that translucency works at all ... but no one ever has." Cute, ain't he? (https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15672)

Comment: I didn't know I couldn't argue, so I asked: "How then does it work when margins are not zero? By the way, thanks for such a marvelous piece of software." (I thought being gentle would help.) The answer: "This is not a place to ask questions. You have the source code: read it for yourself." WOW! I love kind people!

Comment: I cannot exactly reproduce this on R 3.0.2 on a Win7 x64 box, but there are some interesting bugs. If I run the code, the line appears, but if I resize the device window, it disappears. Furthermore, if I run this in RStudio (0.98.501) it works the first time I run the code, but the line will not appear when I run it a second time (the device is refreshed). It doesn't appear until I restart RStudio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to grDevices help, (`?dev.capabilities`)

> Most recent devices support semi-transparent colours provided the graphics format does (which PostScript does not). On the other hand, relatively few graphics formats support (fully or semi-) transparent backgrounds: generally the latter is found only in *PDF and PNG plots*.

Which seems to be right in line with the original questions reported behaviour and the reported response to the filed bug report. (see the comments)

> This is a function of how Windows' GDI handles translucency (transparency works just fine, but that colour is not transparent). ...

Comment: And what is the difference between transparency and translucency?